# Swift Optionals (or Haskell's Maybe) in Python?

Tags: python, swift, haskell, option-type

In Swift I can do `var?.prop`. This results in `nil` if `var` is `nil`, else it results in the value of the `prop` property of `var`.

Equivalently, I can do `var >>= prop` in Haskell, which gives me `None` is `var` is `None`, else it gives me the value of applying `prop` to the value inside `var` (wrapped in `Just`).

Is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: Confusing title and tags.

Comment: You can use a conditional expression:  `var.prop if var else var` but in general in python you're expected to know when something is None and when it isn't and not ask over and over.

Comment: @Snusmumrikken Not really, it's really clear, you just need to understand the concepts of Swift or Haskell to be able to understand it

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve* with this? Could you give a less abstract example?

Comment: Are you asking how to check for None, or how to check if a variable exists (won't raise a NameError)?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, what you describe is `fmap prop var`, not `var >>= prop`, though it seems `var >>= prop` more closely describes what you are looking for, since it could result in `None` even if `var` is not itself `None`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers are on the right track in suggesting a conditional expression, but wrong about how to do it.  You can do it this way:

```
None if var is None else var.prop
```

or, equivalently

```
var.prop if var is not None else None
```

There is a [draft PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505) about adding such a feature to Python, and ther has been discussion of it on the Python-ideas mailing list.  It doesn't look like it will be added in the near future (if ever), but reading the PEP will give you an idea of some existing and proposed ways of handling this.

Comment: "The other answers are on the right track in suggesting a conditional expression, but wrong about how to do it. You can do it this way" - how is my anawer wrong if it is identical to yours?

Comment: @EliKorvigo: Your answer was wrong at the time I started writing this, but you then edited it.

Comment: I believe this will be in Python 3.8 as of 2019.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, there is no special syntax to handle optionals (since there are no optionals), though you can use conditional assignment (ternary operator) to mimic the functionality:

```
unpacked_var = var.prop if var is not None else None
```

Though in Python I would rather check whether `var` has the attribute you want to access.

```
unpacked_var = var.prop if hasattr(var, "prop") else None
```

You can write a function to make it shorter

```
def optional(var, attr):
    return getattr(var, attr) if hasattr(var, attr) else None

unpacked_var = optional(var, "prop")
```

There is a less universal way to do this (and less explicit, IMHO):

```
unpacked_var = hasattr(var, "prop") and var.prop or None
```

The problem here is that you'll get `None` if `bool(var.prop) == False`, so you'd better stick to the ternary operator above.

Comment: Well, not exactly. If `var` is sometimes an object with `prop` and sometimes `None`, then it's just the same as an implicit Optional. Python's `var.prop` in this view is similar to `var!.prop` in Swift: it would throw if `var` is `None`. Then, `var` could also be some other object without `prop`: Swift calls this "not implementing the protocol", so a more exact translation is something like `(var! as! havingProp).prop`. And then the main difference is just that Swift makes each assumption of this kind explicit with an exclamation mark.

Comment: “In Python fynamic typing makes it trivial” – since when is an inline conditional trivial compared to `.?`?

Comment: IMO, you should remove the opinion bit - this isn't the place to discuss which language constructs are "weird" and which ones are "trivial". Otherwise, this is a fine answer - I like that you explore various options. (However, the really short answer is: "No. There is no such syntax.")

Comment: @skagedal ok, I removed that

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Yes, I agree that my statement was primarily opinion-based hance inappropriate for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `None` can be tricky for maintaining clean call site code.  It means that you need to have a lot of defensive conditionals.  As you can see from the other answers, there is a lot of support from smart people for this method.

An alternative is to use an **Optional type**, which much like a collection type (list, set, dict, etc.) is explicitly either empty or not, but unlike other collection types, can only hold 1 element.  This means that all your returns from a function return an object with the same capabilities.  Just as with something returning a collection, when things go awry but not exceptionally so, you can return the empty version of that collection (ex. there are no users older than 100 in the db) you can use an optional type to do the same (ex. there is no user in the db with username foobar).

Since python does not come with a built in optional type, I created a small library that provides it: [**optional.py**](https://github.com/cbefus/optional.py).  You can try it out using 'pip install optional.py'.  I welcome comments, feature requests, and contributions.